# how to add the order by Sum function in a query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

i just have this query and I want to add the ordering of its records by the result of the sum function, how to add this?

```
 Select bus.trans_comp_id, 
 SUM(bus.passengers*trips.cost) 
 From bus inner join trips on bus.ID=trips.bus_id 
 group by bus.trans_comp_id
```

out put of this:

```
trans_comp_id  
 1)   1:412000.00
 2)   2:75000.00
```

I want it with desc order to have the out put:

```
trans_comp_id  
 2)   2:75000.00
 1)   1:412000.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the `SUM` function to the `ORDER BY` caluse:

```
Select bus.trans_comp_id, 
 SUM(bus.passengers*trips.cost) 
 From bus inner join trips on bus.ID=trips.bus_id 
 group by bus.trans_comp_id 
 order by SUM(bus.passengers*trips.cost) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an `ORDER BY` clause that makes use of an alias of the computed value defined in the `SELECT` clause:

```
 SELECT bus.trans_comp_id, 
        SUM(bus.passengers*trips.cost) AS s
 FROM bus 
 INNER JOIN trips ON bus.ID=trips.bus_id 
 GROUP BY bus.trans_comp_id
 ORDER BY s DESC
```